# Hashed Password not matching - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I am using Laravel 4, My Database tables / pages were created using an older version of Laravel. Version 3. I believe.

I have a user login system in place and when passing the hashed password from the view to the controller, It doesn't match the Databases' password at all.

My Hashed codes are :

**Database**

> $08$wqCWqMgG7SRIukdyNEbXX.kK5c.8BxqzGVJSaCC55eKndFjqrJqJG

**Form**

> $2y$10$hJQsF7.KkuXw4GYb8vk1o.SZhdocP7e8SxcjvBWjtLzpJPBlX0f5q

My Laravel controller code is :

```
public function postLogin()
    {

        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Hash::make(Input::get('Password'));

        dd($password);

        $credentials = array(
            'user_email' => Input::get('UserName'),
            'user_password' => Input::get('Password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('users/login')
                           ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                           ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Is it down to an older version of the DB not matching? Any suggestions on what I can check / change to match.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new hash of the same secret will be different every time because a random salt is added while hashing. To check a secret against a hash use:

```
Hash::check('secret', 'hash-of-secret');
```

---

The reason why `Auth::attempt` is failing is that the passed credentials always need to have an `password` key. (Even if your DB field has a different name)

```
$credentials = array(
    'user_email' => Input::get('UserName'),
    'password' => Input::get('Password')
);
```

Then make sure that your `User` model implements this method:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->user_password;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I had "user_password" switching to 'password' did the job. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Hashes will not 'match' when you compare them like that. There is a salt that is added to all hashes.

The problem is most likely your database column name for passwords. If it is `user_passwords` - then you must have set that in your user model or it wont work (Laravel will assume it is `password` otherwise)

So your `$credentials` MUST use the `password` field - not `user_password`

```
$credentials = array(
            'user_email' => Input::get('UserName'),
            'password' => Input::get('Password')
        );
```

If your user database has the password in a column called 'password'. Then you dont need to do anything further. But if your column is called 'user_password' - then you must modify your `User` model and add/modify the following function to this:

Now in User model (app/models/User.php) file you need to add the following function:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->user_password;
}
```

Comment: Wow looks like we wrote pretty much the same answer simultaneously ;)